# submodules are not implement in rtl schematic

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I want to implement my single cycle risc-v project on fpga.
after simulating my code it worked fine .for first step i tried to see my design rtl schematic i got so many warnings like my sub modules are not connected to top module.and i have a black box that has nothing in it.here is my topmodule.
my search told me its about i/o.then i implement io_inst_addr and in_inst and memory_writeBack to see if it is solved and nothing happend.just i had write back module that its outputs are connected to ground.

```
module risc_v_module(
 input [31:0] in_inst,
 input [6:0] io_inst_addr ,
 input clk,
 input rst,
 output [63:0] memory_writeBack
);

 wire [63:0] pc_mem ;
 wire [63:0] ins_addr ;
 wire [63:0] mem_add_out;
 wire [31:0] instruction;
 wire [63:0] dataToReg;


 wire branch ; wire memRead ; wire memWrite ;
 wire memToReg  ; wire [1:0] aluOP;
 wire aluSrc;

 wire [63:0] data1_reg;wire [63:0] data2_reg;
 wire [63:0] signEx; wire [9:0] func_out;


 wire [63:0] in2mem;wire zero;
 wire [63:0] aluRes;wire [63:0] branch_addr;

 wire [63:0] memory_out ; wire [63:0] alu_mem_out ;


 fetch risc_v_fetch(
 .clk(clk),
 .rst(rst),
 .io_inst(in_inst),
 .io_addr(io_inst_addr),
 .new_pc(pc_mem),
 .pc_out(ins_addr),
 .add_out(mem_add_out),
 .instruction(instruction)
 );

 decode risc_v_decode(
 .instruction(instruction),
 .writeData(dataToReg),
 .branch(branch),
 .memRead(memRead),
 .memToReg(memToReg),
 .aluOP(aluOP),
 //.pcSrc(pcSrc),
 .aluSrc(aluSrc),
 .memWrite(memWrite),
 .data1(data1_reg),
 .data2(data2_reg),
 .sign_extend(signEx),
 .function_7_3(func_out)
 );

 execute risc_v_execute(
 .in1(data1_reg),
 .in2(data2_reg),
 .from_signExtend(signEx),
 .aluOP(aluOP),
 .aluSrc(aluSrc),
 .function_7_3(func_out),
 .pc_out(ins_addr),
 .memory_data(in2mem),
 .zero(zero),
 .aluRes(aluRes),
 .add_branch(branch_addr)
 );

 memory risc_v_memory(
 .branch(branch),
 .zero(zero),
 .add_branch(branch_addr),
 .add_out(mem_add_out),
 .aluRes(aluRes),
 .data_write(in2mem),
 .memRead(memRead),
 .memWrite(memWrite),
 .memOut(memory_out),
 .aluOut(alu_mem_out),
 .new_pc(pc_mem)
 );

 write_back ris_v_WB(
 .memtoReg(memToReg),
 .memoryOut(memory_out),
 .aluOut(alu_mem_out),
 .data_to_reg(dataToReg),
 .io_out(memory_writeBack)
 );endmodule
```

Comment: We're not going to be able to help without seeing the code inside write_back. And even that might not be enough. Have you tried simulating first?

Comment: @dave_59 yes I actually did that.the results were correct worekd fine.
I thought that it might not be of the sub modules inside and it about topmodule which cant connect sub modules together .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this lately :
[all submodules outputs should be connect to i/o ports of topmodule in case of getting rtl schematic or map and routing](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/WARNING-Xst-1290-Hierarchical-block-is-unconnected-in-block-lt/td-p/126600)

thanks to [gszakscs](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/138)